# Mass rename of filenames

Tags: files, rename

I have filenames like:

```
Some Text (1).jpg
Some Text (2).jpg
..
Some Text (15).jpg
Some Text (16).jpg
..
Some Text (101).jpg
Some Text (102).jpg
```

And I would like to add `0` befor the numbers, so that I have always 3 numbers. The upper examples would become:

```
Some Text (001).jpg
Some Text (002).jpg
..
Some Text (015).jpg
Some Text (016).jpg
..
Some Text (101).jpg
Some Text (102).jpg
```

Is there any way to automate that?

Comment: I think this question should have a million duplicate answers in stack exchange.... Are your file names containing spaces?

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou yes

Comment: Does your system have the perl-based `prename` / `rename` command?

Comment: @steeldriver Yes it looks like `$ prename` `Usage: rename [-v] [-n] [-f] perlexpr [filenames]`

Comment: I tried different links now. I have to say I do not have much experience in Linux bash nor I have with regex. @Costas I tried it like this: `rename 's/(?<=-)([0-9]+)/sprintf "%03d", $1/e' 'Some Text (*).jpg'` without success

Comment: @steeldriver I tried to edit your example to my needs. Looks like I do something wrong, I get the error: `$ ./rename.sh` `./rename.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''`

Comment: @nbar : Try this one as a test: `nm="a a (01).txt";number=$(grep -Eo '[0-9]*' <<<$nm);sed "s/([0-9]*).txt/(00$number).txt/"<<<$nm` Works ok in my bash.

Comment: The `\r` usually indicates that you have DOS-style line endings in your script. That's a separate issue that you will need to address. If you want to use the perl-based rename, try `prename -nv -- 's/\((\d+)\)/sprintf "(%03d)", $1/e' *.jpg`. If that works satisfactorily, remove the `n` option.

Comment: @steeldriver ah sure, makes sence. you example works great. Thanks. Not sure if I am able to understand it

Answer (score 0):

Also this works ok :

```
for file in *.jpg
do 
  number=$(grep -Eo '[0-9]*' <<<$file)
  newname=$(sed "s/([0-9]*).txt/(0$number).txt/"<<<$file)
  #echo "old file = $file - new name=$newname"
  mv "$file" "$newname"
done
```